# Query over 3 tables and different columns

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to do a fairly simple query, but I cant figure out, how to join the tables together. I am new to this world of SQL and after reading documentation of JOIN and SELECT clauses, I still can't figure this one out.
Here are my 3 tables:

**Seller**

```
|SELLER_ID|NUMBER|FIRST_NAME|LAST_NAME|TEAM_NR|
|        1|105   |John      |Smith    |1      |
|        2|106   |James     |Brown    |3      |
|        3|107   |Jane      |Doe      |3      |
|        4|108   |Nicole    |Sanchez  |2      |
```

**Service**

```
|SERVICE_ID|CODE|NAME     |PRICE |SELLER_ID|CLIENT_ID|
|         1| 502|BLAHBLAH |200   |2        |2        |
|         2| 503|BLAHBLAH2|175   |1        |3        |
|         3| 504|BLAHBLAH3|250   |3        |2        |
|         4| 505|BLAHBLAH4|130   |2        |4        |
```

**Client**

```
|CLIENT_ID|NUMBER |FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |
|        1|51     |JOHN       | ADAMS     |
|        2|52     |MARY       | BRYANT    |
|        3|53     |FRANCIS    | JOHNSON   |
|        4|55     |BEN        | CASTLE    |
```

The goal of this query would be to figure out which team(TEAM_NR from Seller) sold the most services in a month, on the basis of total amount sold(sum of PRICE from Service)

The result should display FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME and TEAM_NR of everyone in the "winning" team.

I already looked for help from StackOverFlow and Google and tried editing these according to my tables, but they didn't pan out.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT S.FIRST_NAME, S.LAST_NAME, S.TEAM_NR, sum(R.PRICE) Winning
FROM Seller S 
    LEFT JOIN Service R ON (S.SELLER_ID=R.SELLER_ID)
GROUP BY S.TEAM_NR,  S.FIRST_NAME, S.LAST_NAME
```

**EDIT** Don't even need any join on Client table.

**EDIT 2** All fields from the SELECT have to be in the GROUP BY.

Comment: "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"" error when trying to run it

Comment: Syntax on the first line, forgot a “,”

Comment: With Oracle, all the SELECT fields have to be in the GROUP BY.

Comment: Thank you, this solved it. But how can I get the total amount of sales per team? For an example: Person1 from team A sold $20 worth and Person2 also from team A sold $50 worth. Their sales in total would be $70. How can I get that total amount for each team?

Comment: If you want to have the sum for the team, remove the “seller” fields, from the select, and from the GROUP BY.
If you really want to have the sum per team, and have the seller informations per line, you will have to do a subquery.